# Apache2 & eruby, as 10 years ago

Tags: html, ruby, apache, eruby

Why can't I use eruby without Rails ? I don't like Rails, but it seems eruby has not been used without Rails for a decade (If I refer on the dates of the lasts questions about eruby on Stack Overflow).

Here are the lines that I added to my Apache configuration to handle .erb scripts :

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-erb .erb
Action application/x-httpd-erb "/cgi-bin/erb-cgi.rb"
```

When I try to load a simple test page (located on myserver.fr/test.erb), I get the following error :

> The requested URL /cgi-bin/erb-cgi.rb/test.erb was not found on this server.

It seems like Apache try to open "/cgi-bin/erb-cgi.rb/test.erb" instead of running /cgi-bin/erb-cgi.rb with test.erb as a parameter (what should be the normal behavior of the Action directive)

I don't detail here the /cgi-bin/erb-cgi.rb script, the server doesn't even try to open it.
It was working for the whole world 10 year ago, I don't think I'm doing something wrong... Am I ? (Of course I am)

And yes, I'm french, so there is a nonzero probability that my English is bad. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but if you want easy templating in Ruby without Rails, you may want to have a look at [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com), a very lightweight framework build in Ruby.

Sinatra can be run in a single command, manages routes and templates, and that's about it.